# Qual è il significato di "porgere la battuta"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> Quella sera Iris era sublime: perfettamente padrona di sé, ci faceva ridere alle lacrime con certe storielle assurde e succose che aveva, credo, inventato o arricchito lì per lì.
>
> Almerighi, che era un bell'uomo, le stava seduto accanto e **le porgeva la battuta**: facevano del cabaret.

Non capisco cosa significa che Almerighi "le porgeva la battuta". Ho cercato "porgere la battuta" nel [Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/), ma non l'ho trovato. Sapreste spiegarmi il suo significato?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'espressione viene dal linguaggio del teatro. La *battuta* è la frase di un attore o di un'attrice. Nella definizione 5 del vocabolario Treccani (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/battuta/) si trova «dare [= porgere] la b., dare all’attore lo spunto per la replica, da parte del suggeritore o dell’interlocutore».

L'autrice vuol dire che Iris e Almerighi sono come una coppia collaudata di attori: Almerighi dice frasi o fa domande perché Iris possa raccontare cose divertenti, assurde, succose. "Fare del cabaret" significa che facevano divertire tutti come fossero al cabaret (i cui spettacoli avevano proprio queste caratteristiche).

Nel linguaggio del teatro, l'attore che porge la battuta di solito si chiama *spalla*.

Comment: Grazie, @Benedetta! Non sapevo che "dare la battuta" e "porgere la battuta" erano la stessa cosa.

Comment: @Charo "porgere" è un sinonimo più gentile e meno usato di "dare".